# Redux-Form: How to update parent store state by reducer in Redux

Tags: redux-form

Scenario : FiledArray was placed in Redux form  and it contains five records. I deleted 2 records and tried to update the deleted record IDs in database.

Issue: Unable to get deleted record details while submitting the redux form.

Is it possible to update redux-form state through reducer? How can I proceed to get record id which I deleted?

Comment: Minor grammar improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the ***action creators*** provided by `redux-form` for updating a form's state programattically.

https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/

You won't be able to do it easily with your own custom reducer, so you should only try that approach if all else fails

Comment: Thanks bitstrider  for your response. "arrayRemove(form:String, field:String, index:Number) action is fired when i deleting field array record.but this action contains only index value rather than record ID. can you please advise to get recordID which i deleted.